# 2 or more Zend apps on a single host with base url rewrite

Tags: apache, zend-framework, tomcat, apache-config

how can i configure my zend apps so that they can be accessed on the same domain like the one found on apache tomcat
e.g. if you have two applications deployed on apache tomcat server you can access them like

```
http://localhost:8080/AplicationOne
http://localhost:8080/ApplicationTWo
```

now what i want to have is if i have 2 apps X and Y :
i want to access application X using htp://myhost/X  and application Y  htp://myhost/X
and if i am on the root htp://myhost just some dumb page or list of apps X,Y,..

using only .htacess and rewrite base

***** WHAT I AM HAVING CURRENTLY IS 3 files with this setting ****

(how can i change these settings to achieve the above requirement)< ==== my real question ?

baseurl = "http://myhost"       === > in the application.ini file

.httaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]  
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

add entry to /etc/hosts

> 127.0.0.1       myhost

enable apache host myhost   =====> /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myhost

> VirtualHost *:80>
>       ServerName myhost

Comment: PLease use the code tag and whats going on witht he fonts? Clean up your question if you want help.

Comment: i can not add the http:// b/se since i can't add links with http:// more than once.
don't have enough points to post links

Comment: is the problem you have Myhost v myhost? look at /etc/hosts cf. locator.local

Comment: no , my problem is not that the configuration is working fine for a single host x with rewrite base /(root) in the .htaccess file 
but not with rewrite_base /x/ and rewrite_base /y/ that are included in two separate .htaccess files for app x and appy 
Thank You, though Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have posted this question there also ( https://serverfault.com/questions/207741/how-to-deploay-two-zend-frame-work-based-apps-in-apache2-like-the-one-in-tomcat/207776#207776) but later i got it working myself. got help from here http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Configuring+Your+URL+Rewriter

Answer (score 0):

I have these situation in one of my works, and I use subdomains to each application but just with one Zend core. At the apache I wrote the virtual host for each domain and put the .htacces for the rewrite inside de public_html for each domain.

Regard´s.

Comment: i want the same domain b/se some how it shows some kind of organizational structure  for example :  http://domain.com/ZendApp1 ,                                        
 http://domain.com/ZendApp2

Comment: You must separate it at you public_html folder! Than you just point the index.php of each folder like ZendApp2 and ZendApp1 for their folders inside application folder.